# How to make this function work more efficiently to count dominators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I have to make a function where it would count the amount of dominators in a given list (number to the right of any number has to be smaller for it to be counted as a dominator.) For example, given the list `[53,7,14,11,4,7]` the function would return `4` since 53,14,11,7 are dominators(last item on the list is a dominator). Issue is that it takes a very long time to run for larger integers. Was just wondering if there is a less brute and more efficient way to achieve the same result?

Here's what I have:

```
def count_dominators(items): # works but takes a very long time to execute.
    k = 0
    for idx,item in enumerate(items):

        dominator = True
        for ritem in items[idx+1:]:

            if item<=ritem:
                dominator = False
                break
        if dominator:

            k = k+1        
    return k
```

Comment: all you need to do is to show that a number is larger than any dominator to its right. By definition, the dominator is the largest number of the right subsequence.

Answer (score 2):

Going backwards, you get a linear-time algorithm:

```py
def count_dominators(items):
    rev = list(reversed(items))
    if rev:
        max = rev[0]
        count = 1
        for i in range(1,len(rev)):
            if rev[i] > max:
                max = rev[i]
                count += 1
    else:
        count = 0
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives a linear time algorithm and avoids copying the input list (helpful if the list is large):

```
import math

def count_dominators(numbers):
    count = 0
    max = -math.inf
    for number in reversed(numbers):
        if number > max:
            max = number
            count += 1
    return count
```